# Azure devops - perform same action for a collection of directories from drop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

From Azure Devops (VSTS), I have an build artifact package that has a directory structure like this:

- Drop

  - Service.First
  - Service.Second
  - Service.Third
  - Service.Forth
  - etc...(several more folders)

Each folder contains a service.

The folder is named the same as the service executable.

In my release pipeline, is there a way to iterate over each folders, copy the contents into the program files directory, and install each service based on the name of the folder?

I am trying to avoid having to crate separate deployment group tasks for each service.

Comment: You can do it with Powershell (then you have only 1 PowerShell task for all the services).

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk can you point me at example?  Specifically iterating the directory structure capturing the current directory?

Comment: Check this: https://pastecode.xyz/view/399aa7ab, I iterate for the folders and copy them to Program Files.